# How can I toggle fullscreen for the embedded VLC player

Tags: vb.net, winforms, activex, embed, vlc

I am embedding the VLC media player into a Windows Forms application through an activeX control.
The code goes like this:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Open file button
    Dim openFileDialog1 As New OpenFileDialog()
    openFileDialog1.Title = "Open file"
    If openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.add(openFileDialog1.FileName)
    End If
    openFileDialog1.Dispose()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    'Play button
    AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.play()
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    'Stop button
    AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.stop()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Pause button
    AxVLCPlugin21.playlist.togglePause()
End Sub

Private Sub TrackBar1_Scroll(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TrackBar1.Scroll
    'Volume control
    AxVLCPlugin21.audio.Volume = TrackBar1.Value
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    'Toggle Full Screen button
    AxVLCPlugin21.video.toggleFullscreen()
End Sub

End Class
```

How can I toggle full screen?

This code makes no effect:

```
AxVLCPlugin21.video.toggleFullscreen()
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `AxVLCPlugin21.video.fullscreen = Not AxVLCPlugin21.video.fullscreen`?

Comment: Hi, Reza Aghaei. This makes no effect either. AxVLCPlugin21.video.toggleFullscreen() changes the value of AxVLCPlugin21.video.fullscreen, but alas there is no visual change.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (axVLCPlugin21.video.fullscreen)
    axVLCPlugin21.video.fullscreen = false;
else
    axVLCPlugin21.video.fullscreen = true;
```